# Display DataFrame in tkinter library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

i want to create  a simple GUI form, which asks user to  browse file  and then display result, i have wrote following code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
def read_file():
    filename =askopenfilename()
    label1.insert(0,filename)
    return
def display_file():
    filename1 =label1.get()
    data =pd.read_csv(filename1)
    print(data.head())
root =Tk()
#root.withdraw()
label1 =Entry(root,width=100)
button =Button(root,text="Read csv file",command=read_file)
button1 =Button(root,text="Display  file",command=display_file)
button.pack()

label1.pack()
button1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

result  is following image :
[image]

when i  click read csv file, it gives me possibility to read file  and result is like this :
[image]

now i need display part :

```
def display_file():
    filename1 =label1.get()
    data =pd.read_csv(filename1)
    print(data.head())
```

this function just display files in working directory, but i need to show(5  rows of dataframe) in GUI form, let us  suppose that  file  contains  just two column -  please tell me  how to do? i have searched a lot  but could not find exact  solution (different solutions  was presented and i was confused)

Comment: Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Please post your good faith effort at solving this problem and edit your question to a specific issue needing resolution

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a Tkinter element where you want the data to be displayed (here, I choose Label) using a Variable element and set this element to hold your data from inside the display_file formula:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


def read_file():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    label1.insert(0, filename)
    return


def display_file():
    filename1 = label1.get()
    data = pd.read_csv(filename1)
    print(data.head())
    pd_variable.set(data.head())


root = Tk()
# root.withdraw()
label1 = Entry(root, width=100)
button = Button(root, text="Read csv file", command=read_file)
button1 = Button(root, text="Display  file", command=display_file)
pd_variable = Variable(root)
label2 = Label(root, textvariable=pd_variable)
button.pack()

label1.pack()
button1.pack()
label2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```